# How to change ActiveMQ KahaDB directory in TomEE

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-tomee

From the TomEE 9 console I can see that the activeMQ KahaDB is using `C:\Windows\system32\activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB` as its default storage directory.

```
Jun 29, 2023 10:00:01 AM org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService <clinit>
INFO: Loaded the Bouncy Castle security provider at position: 14
Jun 29, 2023 10:00:02 AM org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService 
doStartPersistenceAdapter
INFO: Using Persistence Adapter: 
KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[C:\Windows\system32\activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB]
Jun 29, 2023 10:00:02 AM org.apache.activemq.store.SharedFileLocker doStart
INFO: Database activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB\lock is locked by another server. This broker is now in slave mode waiting a lock to be acquired
```

Since `C:\Windows\system32` is a protected folder it is causing the ActiveMQ to split out this INFO

```
INFO: Database activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB\lock is locked by another server. This broker is now in slave mode waiting a lock to be acquired
```

I found [this link](https://activemq.apache.org/kahadb) that documents how I can custom configure the KahaDB.  The configuration looks simple enough, but
I just don't know what xml file to put the configuration in?  I tried `server.xml` but it didn't work.

Below is the content of server.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
--><!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
  <Server port="18005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- TomEE plugin for Tomcat -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!-- APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>
    
  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="18080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="18443" server="Apache TomEE" xpoweredBy="false"/>
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="18080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="18443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
         This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
         SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
         library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the AprLifecycleListener.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
         the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="18443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" xpoweredBy="false" server="Apache TomEE" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 18009 -->
    <!--
    <Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="::1"
               port="18009"
               redirectPort="18443" />
    -->

    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

      <broker brokerName="broker">
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="/var/apps/apache-tomee-plus-9.0/boss/usmo/Boss/resources/jmsQueues" journalMaxFileLength="32mb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>
      </broker>
    
      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"/>

      <Context docBase="Boss" path="/Boss" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Boss"/><Context docBase="dhiveCommandXML" path="/dhiveCommandXML" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:dhiveCommandXML"/></Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally able to configure the TOMEE activemq to use a different KahaDB folder.  I followed the instructions from [document](https://tomee.apache.org/jms-resources-and-mdb-container.html) (See the 'Internal ActiveMQ Broker with activemq.xml' section).  Below is a short summary of the instructions and some additional notes:

1. download and add the following jars into tomee server's lib folder:

```
spring-beans-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
xbean-spring-3.9.jar
activemq-spring-5.8.0.jar (This one is not mentioned in the document)
activemq_spring-expression-5.3.29.jar (This one is not mentioned in the document)
```

2. Add tomee.xml to the tomee server's conf folder.  See example below.  Note: BrokerXmlConfig is where you specify the url of the activemq configure file (note: I was unable to use relative path (like conf/activemq.xml).  So, I ended up using absolute path)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>
  <!-- see http://tomee.apache.org/containers-and-resources.html -->

  <!-- activate next line to be able to deploy applications in apps -->
  <!-- <Deployments dir="apps" /> -->
  

    <Resource id="BossJmsResourceAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
        BrokerXmlConfig =  xbean:file:/var/apps/apache-tomee-plus-9.0/boss/usmo/Boss/resources/properties/activemq.xml
        ServerUrl       =  vm://localhost
    </Resource>

    <Resource id="BossJmsConnectionFactory" type="jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory">
        ResourceAdapter = BossJmsResourceAdapter
    </Resource>

    <Container id="BossJmsMdbContainer" ctype="MESSAGE">
        ResourceAdapter = BossJmsResourceAdapter
    </Container>

    <Resource id="jms/TransactionManager" type="jakarta.jms.Queue"/>
    <Resource id="jms/EmailManager" type="jakarta.jms.Queue"/>

</tomee>
```

3. Create an activemq.xml file at the url specified in step 2. Below is an example of one:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.8.0.xsd">
<!--  Allows us to use external properties as variables in this configuration file  -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" useJmx="true" brokerName="localhost" useShutdownHook="false" persistent="true" start="false" schedulerSupport="false" enableStatistics="false" offlineDurableSubscriberTimeout="259200000" offlineDurableSubscriberTaskSchedule="3600000">
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="/var/apps/apache-tomee-plus-9.0/boss/usmo/Boss/resources/jmsQueues/activemq-data/kaha" indexCacheSize="20000" ignoreMissingJournalfiles="true" checkForCorruptJournalFiles="true" checksumJournalFiles="true"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>
        <!--  The transport connectors ActiveMQ will listen to. Set the same for the serverUrl in the tomee.xml file  -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- Local broker -->
            <transportConnector name="vm" uri="vm://localhost"/>
        </transportConnectors>
    </broker>
</beans>
```

Comment: I edited by answer before seeing yours, but this is correct. The only thing is I would use vm: transport, not tcp:

Comment: Thanks JF.  I have edited the answer to use vm transport.

Comment: should be vm://<broker-name> so vm://Broker in your case

Comment: ops.  I have edited the answer to correct issue with mismatch broker name.

Comment: this is still incorrect. You need to remove :61616 after the end. The VM transport does not use TCP

Comment: remove the :61616.  Somehow it works fine with it also.

Answer (score 1):

`server.xml` is the correct place to put the KahaDB configuration. If this did not work, go ahead and post your entire `server.xml` and startup log, and let's take a look.  The key is you'll have to *edit* the existing persistence adapter section to something like this:

```
<broker>
....

 <persistenceAdapter>
  <kahaDB directory="c:\var\activemq\data\kahadb" journalMaxFileLength="32mb" />
 </persistenceAdapter>

...
</broker>
```

Note that you'll have the same problem with the log directory. It's probably best you put the entire activemq installation somewhere other than `system32`.

## EDIT

I misunderstood that this activemq instace was a part of a TomEE runtime. `server.xml` is not the correct place. The answer is a bit more complicated.

First, for any serious deployment of ActiveMQ, I would run the broker externally. This is just good practice, but if you have exactly one TomEE server, using the embedded instance is fine. To configure this, put the following in `tomee.xml` and adjust the sizes for your needs.

```
    <Resource
        id="ra/activemq"
        type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
        BrokerXmlConfig=
        ServerUrl=ssl://your.activemq.host.com:61616
        threadPoolSize=10
        maximumRedeliveries=0
    </Resource>
    <Resource
        id="jms/xaConnectionFactory"
        type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
        ResourceAdapter=ra/activemq
        poolMaxSize=10
        poolMinSize=1
        connectionMaxWaitTime=5s
        transactionSupport=xa
    </Resource>
```

If you really want to run a local broker and want to configure it, you need to create an `activemq.xml` with whatever settings you want. Start by copying the `activemq.xml` from their git master, and change the settings you want. In this case, you would change the kahadb location.

Next to tell TomEE to use your configuration, you need to load the broker configuration from xml:

```
    <Resource
        id="ra/activemq"
        type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
        BrokerXmlConfig=xbean:activemq.xml
        ServerUrl=vm://localhost
        threadPoolSize=10
        maximumRedeliveries=0
    </Resource>
    <Resource
        id="jms/xaConnectionFactory"
        type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
        ResourceAdapter=ra/activemq
        poolMaxSize=10
        poolMinSize=1
        connectionMaxWaitTime=5s
        transactionSupport=xa
    </Resource>
```

- You'll probably need to add some jar files to the `tomee/lib` directory for XML config support. You can grab these from an activemq download
- `vm://localhost` indicates the connection to the local broker. Make sure your broker name is `localhost`, or change it in both places.

Hope this helps!

Comment: just added the server.xml to the original post.  Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: I stand corrected, that is not the correct place :) I thought you meant your activemq configuration was called server.xml. I'll edit my post later to help you out. If you want to take a crack at it, you need to edit your tomee.xml, not your server.xml

Comment: Yes, will definitely take a crack at it.  Note:  I didn't install the activemq myself; it comes with TOMEE 9.

Answer (score 0):

What stops you to move this activemq/activmq-data directory to non-system32 location?

refer: https://activemq.apache.org/version-5-getting-started.html

Download as zip and make it working from easy location.

Comment: I'm working on migrating some web apps from TOMEE 1.7 to  TOMEE 9.  activemq comes with TOMEE 9.  I didn't install that myself.  If possible, I would prefer to simply use the one that comes with TOMEE 9.